# Basic shell exercise

Tags: shell, permissions, zsh

I have an exercise on shell where I need to work with permissions. I need to reproduce a repository where files should look like this when using ls -l :

```
dr-x---r-- 2 XX XX XX Jun 1 22:45 test0
-rwx--xr-- 1 XX XX 4  Jun 1 22:56 test1
-r-----r-- 2 XX XX 1  Jun 1 22:45 test2
```

so I can reproduce it in some ways (with basic commands like mkdir test0 chmod 504 test0/chmod ugo-rwx) but it will always look like this

```
dr-x---r--@ 2 XX XX 64 Jun 1 22:45 test0
-rwx--xr--  1 XX XX 0  Jun 1 22:54 test1
-r-----r--  1 XX XX 5  Jun 1 22:45 test2
```

As you can see, in test0 I have an "@" and I can't find what it stands for, nor how to delete it. And then, once i create another file or directory, test0 will automatically change and look like this :

```
drwxr-xr-@ 2 XX XX 64 Jun 1 22:45 test0
```

For test1 i don't know how to make so that my file size is "4" and not "0"

For test2 i don't know how it is not a directory and still has 2 linked hard-links and it's size is 1.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What command are you using to enumerate the directory contents?

Comment: Please provide the script you created/used.

Comment: I'm just using basic shell commands, like for test0 I will make

```mkdir test0
chmod 504 test0``` and then i will use chmod ugo-rwx command types to change the permissions

Comment: Then you should update your question to indicate what you used at each step. We shouldn't have to make assumptions about what you are doing as we will more than likely assume wrong.

Comment: @scrappedcola done. I hope it's more understandable now, I'm not using anything complicated here.

Comment: With 'ls -l', you will NOT be able to get test0 to show 'XX XX XX'. The third parameter is the directory size, and will always be numeric

Comment: investigate the `stat` command.

Comment: @Dimiouioui : In the title of your question, you say that you want to use bash, but you are tagging this question with zsh. Please make up your mind first which shell you are planning to use.

Comment: @user1934428 I don't undersand your answer. My question is "basic shell exercise", I tag it as zsh because I work on mac OS with the zsh shell.

Comment: @I need new spectacles. I read it as _bash shell exercise_.

Comment: @user1934428 no problems my dude :)), consider being a little less agressive the next time. Hope you're having a great day ! <3

Comment: Sorry. And: I did not want to sound aggressive. I was just confused.

Answer (score 2):

The @ is a Mac OS convention and means that the directory has been set up with extended permissions. Further information can be found here:

http://scottlab.ucsc.edu/xtal/wiki/index.php/Extended_Attributes

With regards to the size of the files, you can create files and specify their sizes with dd and so:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test1 bs=4c count=1

dd if=/dev/zero of=test2 bs=5c count=1
```

dd details from man pages:

```
  dd - convert and copy a file

  bs=BYTES
          read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time


   count=N
          copy only N input blocks


  N and BYTES may be followed by the following multiplicative suffixes: c
   =1, w =2, b =512, kB =1000, K =1024, MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024, xM =M
   GB =1000*1000*1000, G =1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.
```

Comment: Hey there, after some research I'm trying to find out what the ```dd if=/dev/zero of=test1 bs=4c count=1``` command do.

I can't figure out what the bs= and count= stand for

Comment: I've added details from the dd man pages.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the extended permissions part oddly enough when i try these :

```mkdir test0``` I'll have the "@"

I'll try

```xattr -c test2
   ls -l```

and the "@" dissapears. But when I do :

```chmod 504 test0``` for  some reason the "@" keeps coming back and permissions resets!!!

Comment: For some reason, the extended attribute always resets and i keep getting the "@" back...
I tried the following :

```xattr -c test2```
```xattr test2
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags
xattr -d com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags```